# How to use a template with Ember.CollectionView

Tags: ember.js, collectionview

I'm trying to create a `CollectionView` with a list of items and have it render into the template specified in the `CollectionView`'s `templateName` property. However, I can't get it to work.

it looks like this:

```
App = Ember.Application.create({});

App.ItemView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'item_template',
    tagName: 'li'
});

App.CollectionViewTest = Ember.CollectionView.extend({
    templateName: 'collection_template', 
    itemViewClass: App.ItemView,

    content: [
        { title: 'Item 1' },
        { title: 'Item 2' }
    ]
});
```

with templates like this:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
    <h1>Testing CollectionView TemplateName</h1>
    {{collection App.CollectionViewTest}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="collection_template">
    <h2>The CollectionView Template</h2>
    <ul>
        {{outlet}}
    </ul>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="item_template">
    {{title}}
</script>
```

As it is, the `<h2>` never gets rendered, unless I change `App.CollectionViewTest` to a `Ember.View`, but then, obviously, there's no list items.

Is this a bug? or am I missing something?

-- here's a js fiddle with the code: http://jsfiddle.net/S46vH/

Comment: your http://jsfiddle.net/S46vH/ is basically blank, did you save the latest version before posting here the link?

Comment: oops, no. should have been : http://jsfiddle.net/S46vH/1/ but the problem's solved now. Thanks any how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since [Ember.CollectionView](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.CollectionView.html) is a subclass of [Ember.ContainerView](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ContainerView.html), it does not have a template of its own.

From the API docs:

> A template, templateName, defaultTemplate, layout, layoutName or defaultLayout property on a container view will not result in the template or layout being rendered. The HTML contents of a Ember.ContainerView's DOM representation will only be the rendered HTML of its child views.

To make this work you can move the `collection_template` markup into application template or make it a partial. Then replace `{{outlet}}` with `{{collection App.CollectionViewTest}}`

Comment: ah, that makes sense. I was confused by the fact that `template` and `templateName` are both listed as properties on the Ember API `CollectionView` page. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Yeah that's tripped me up a few times as well.